# Booting ubuntu of a usb 3.0 pen drive. Is it using the superspeed

Tags: usb, persistence

Installed ubuntu 12.04 with persistence using  unetbootin on a usb 3.0 pen drive. Now booting from it..

I am not asking if ubuntu supports usb 3.0 . It does

I am asking if it is connected at Superspeed or just at usb 2.0 speeds ? Is there anything I can do to verify that it is actually running at usb 3.0 speeds ? That is my question.

The reason for doubt is that windows sometimes shows "connected @ usb 3.0 " and sometimes "this device can do faster at usb 3.0"

I do have the blue usb 3.0 ports.

Answer (score 1):

a simple test:

USB 2.0 is defined as a technologie which can transport data from a to b with a speed up to 60 Megabytes per second. (We are talking about Megabytes, not Megabits.) But You will seldom find an USB 2.0 device that needs this speed and never find an USB 2.0 pen drive that can reach this speed.

So make the following test:
Just take some big files like movies or so and copy them from your pen drive to your computer hard drive. You should take more than 1 Gigabytes. Before starting, you check how big your package of files is. Then you start and observe the seconds on your watch.
When it is finished, you can calculate how much Megabytes per second this operation has reached.

When it is more than 60 MB/s you can be sure that USB 3.0 is supported.

A good 3.0 pen drive should make 100 MB/s or more in this test.
(In this direction)

Be careful:
Copying the files from the hard drive to the pen drive will normally take more time than the other direction. "Reading" from the pen drive can be more than twice as fast as "Writing" on the pen drive.

The "reading" speed of your hard drive should normally be much faster than the "writing" speed of your pen drive. So the copying of data from hard drive to pen drive can show you the writing speed limit of your pen drive.

But a good 3.0 pen drive reading speed can be faster than a hard drive writing speed.

When the "reading" speed of your pen drive is faster than the "writing" speed of your hard drive, this simple test can not show you the reading speed limit of your pen drive.

An other problem: The NTFS file system, which is normally used on Microsoft Windows computers can be a brake for linux operating systems. Copying files from a NTFS drive to an other NTFS drive with a linux operating system can take twice as much time as copying exactly the same files from a linux ext4 drive to an other ext4 drive.

Have fun on testing

Ulrik